# Update model, delete its array and populate new array using MongoDB Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I wish to ask for advice on the best way to do the following performance-wise.

so, for example, I have a model

```
person :{
  _id: "12312",
  name: "hello",
  phones: [
     { number : "123456" }
  ]
}
```

when I update the person model, like the name: "newname", I also wish to clear the phone array and populate it with a new one.

i was thinking of doing a findById/findOne().deleteArray().populateArray() chaining.

what would be the best path to chain it in Mongoose?

I figure deleting the array is the quickest since the id is a random alphanumeric and not some incrementing long value so might as well delete everything and recreate the array

thoughts?

This is my function in Express/Mongoose

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.person_id, person, { new: true, runValidators: true }, function(err, person) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(person);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the phones array with an empty array with findOneAndUpdate like this:

```
const newDoc = {
  name: "newname",
  phones: []
}

let doc = await Person.findOneAndUpdate({ name: newDoc.name }, newDoc, {
  new: true
});

console.log(doc);
```

or if you want to replace existing phones with new ones you can use an object like this:

```
const newDoc = {
  name: "newname",
  phones: ["1","2"]
}
```

Comment: thanks. this does clear one thing. but can i chain this such that i would like to add a new array to the phone property after is has been cleared?

Comment: @chitgoks  yes you can replace the existing phones, with new ones, as I updated in the answer.

Comment: thank you. one last thing. i modified the json because i actually forgot to include the id (my bad). my goal is to look it via id and then replace the whole document. Would this be Person.findById(id).update(....) ?

Comment: @chitgoks there is already a helper method for this in mongoose, findByIdAndUpdate. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: Thank you that is what i am looking for. one last question. sorry, im not sure why my code says "Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'. i am using findIdAndUpdate so it should ignore updating the id field.

Comment: @chitgoks are you trying to update the value of _id, if so it is not a good practice

Comment: ok so it seems that when i instantiate a new Mongoose model , it creates itself a new _id. i thought the id is generated once those save() functions are called. what i am currently doing is get the req.param person id, then call findIdAndUpdate and then update the whole document by passing the req.body object.

so what i did is manually set the id property with the value from the request object.

Comment: @chitgoks  don't pass your _id to the model, it generates itself

Comment: i didnt pass it but it created an id property when i created a new Person(). so my workaround is to set the id property with the correct one. thanks for the help suleymansah